# Get attribute of a property in python

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a decorator which simply caches return values (called `@cached` in my example) and I wish to use it in conjunction with `@property`. This works just fine normally. The problem I am facing occurs when I try and use an `expire` attribute added by `@cached`.

```
def cached(f):
    cache = [None]

    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        if cache[0]:
            cache[0] = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return cache[0]

    def expire():
        cache[0] = None

    inner.expire = expire
    return inner

class Example(object):
    @property
    @cached
    def something_expensive(self):
        print("expensive")
        return "hello"


e = Example()
e.something_expensive
e.something_expensive.expire()
```

How am I able to get access to the expire function? added to the function after its replaced by `@property`. I understand **why** this doesn't work I am interested in a way of working around that problem.

Some restrictions:

- I cannot change the `@cached` decorator its in a library I don't control
- I would really rather not remove `@property` because I want to expire in my unit tests and they make my code much nicer to use.

One solution that I think is rather bad is (because In reality I have a lot of properties that I want to do this for):

```
class Example(object):
    @cached
    def _something_expensive(self):
        return "hello"

    @property
    def something_expensive(self):
        return self._something_expensive()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it using the class dictionary:

```
type(e).__dict__['something_expensive'].fget.expire()
```

In general `e.something_expensive` is equivalent to:

```
type(e).__dict__['something_expensive'].__get__(e, type(e))
```

For more details read up: [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html)

Note that inside the `expiry` function you're not setting `cache` from the outer function `cached` function as `None`, you're simply creating a new local variable. You may want to do something like this:

```
def expire():
    del cache[:]
    cache.append(None)
```

In Python 3 it's even easier to update `cache` using the [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-nonlocal_stmt) keyword.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate the help. The cache = None is a typo ill fix that